# HighCharts - update / redraw / addAxis when detect selection event

Tags: highcharts

I have a datetime chart to show daily data within 3 years in a series,
I set the x-Axis formatter to display month of a year in the general view
[Screen Capture of General View](http://postimg.org/image/izwj0cvdv/)
I set the 'zoomtype' to 'x', when it zoom to daily level,
the x-axis still show the month base on the formatter I set before
[Screen Capture zoomto daily level](http://postimg.org/image/mcfgk4y2b/)
How can I change my x-axis formatter when detect zoom action?

```
formatter: function () { // Single digit month                          
                var mth = Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value).replace(/^[0]+/g, " ");
                var year = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value);

                if (mth == 'Jan')
                    return mth + '<br>' + year;
                else
                    return mth;
            },
```

Some Method I have tried, but failed :
1) Make 3 different x-axis stand for 'day', 'month' and 'year', add/remove those axis when different zoom level is detected
2) use chart.update() in selection event
3) use chart.redraw() in selection event

Thanks!!


 **update** 
Thanks Pawel, I have tried below syntax inside the xAxis Formatter, but seems cannot return the getExtremes correctly,
please kindly advice, thanks!!

```
var extreme = this.getExtremes();
var extreme = this.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
```

Comment: Simple jsFiddle would be helpful. Anyway, in formatter you have access to `this.axis`, so you can get extremes: `this.axis.getExtremes()`. Now according to range on a chart, you can display specific format on xAxis.

Comment: Thanks, Pawel, I have tried the setExtreme(), but it seems can return correctly, please see the update, thank a lot!

Comment: Read my comment once again, it should be: `this.axis.getExtremes()` ;) Not `xAxis[0]`, neither second option.

Comment: I have got it, now trying the formatter setting for different zoom level, thank you very much :)